# Timetabling in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a timetable in Prolog, where there are 10 teachers, 5 classes and 3 groups of students. Each *teacher* must teach all 5 classes in a week, and one group at a time with at least 2 hours break

```
%% professors/10
professors([coe,chr,dan,dar,ell,elv,frank,franc,ric,rac]).

%% classes/5
classes(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5).

%%classrooms/3
seat(10,30,70).

%%daysoftheweek/5
day(monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday).
```

Comment: Please do *not* use lists or parameters for the individual days, professors, classes, etc. Usually those are represented as *individual* facts.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have tried creating some clauses using these objects as predicates, but it is not printing the time table

Comment: willem , can they be use to construct the DCGs?